# Нужна помощь в понимании замыканий

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Знаю что написано на эту тему уже немало, но всё же

Итак, шло все как по маслу (в плане изучения js) пока я к замыканиям не дошел) читаю, смотрю ролики на эту тематику - и просто ну нивкакую не могу понять, как это работает и зачем это нужно..?
если с определением/пониманием что такое замыкания более менее понятно... хотя тут тоже все не так однозначно... вот что пишут несколько источников по даному вопросу:

> MDN: Замыкание — это комбинация функции и лексического окружения, в
>   котором эта функция была определена.
>
> javascript.ru: Замыкание – это функция вместе со всеми внешними
>   переменными, которые ей доступны.

в неткоторых недалеких источниках:

> это функция внутри другой функции

)

Вот так вот, поди пойми эти замыкания, если многие даже их определить нормыльным языком не могут (

перейдём непосредственно к коду

вот пример замыканий с сайта w3schools:

```html
<body>

<p>Counting with a local variable.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Count!</button>

<p id="demo">0</p>

<script>
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
})();

function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add();
}
</script>

</body>
```

Вопрос - зачем нужны все эти renurn'ы? если первый как я понимаю еще возвращает функцию, то зачем нужен второй и почему без него у counter'a значение undefined?

```js
function makeAdder(x) {
  return function(y) {
    return x + y;
  };
};

var add5 = makeAdder(5);
var add10 = makeAdder(10);

console.log(add5(2));  // 7
console.log(add10(2)); // 12
```

почему нельзя поставить измененные параметры сразу при вызове (напр., makeAdder(2) а не (add5(2)) ), то есть зачем нужно сперва присваивать функцию в переменную?

процитирую наконец еще один источник (тот же MDN):

> Замыкания — это функции, ссылающиеся на независимые (свободные)
>   переменные. Другими словами, функция, определённая в замыкании,
>   «запоминает» окружение, в котором она была создана. Это окружение состоит из произвольного количества локальных переменных, которые были в области действия функции во время создания замыкания.

что здесь понимается под "окружением" кроме переменных или только переменные? насколько "долго" замыкание может помнить такое окружение?

p.s. не кидайтесь тапкми за возможно по нубски сформулированные вопросы)

Answer (score 2):

Можете почитать по дубликату о подробностях.

При создании функции, ей создаётся ссылка на родительское окружение, в котором она создана.
Т. е. при отсутствии у себя в окружении, допустим, переменной, движок может пойти по ссылке в родительский скоуп и там отыскать.

1. Функция `add` вызывается сама при создании, возвращает новую функцию, но с захваченной переменной-счетчиком в замыкании.
   При вызове `add`, сработает внутренняя функция, изменит значение и вернёт его.
   Почему `return` нужен? Ну без него функции возвращают `undefined` (кроме стрелок. Иногда).
2. Синтетический пример просто.
   Но показывающий возможности замыкания - создал фабрикой (паттерн) особую функцию, уже заряженную чем-либо (тут просто особенной цифрой) и можно ею манипулировать, зная что везде, где применяешь, будут заданные ранее параметры.

---

Представим функцию, при создании которой всегда создаётся её окружение (кладём туда переменные, определённые в ней, внутреннюю информации и т. п.).
Внутри создаём ещё одну функцию, для которой тоже создаётся объект окружения, но так же есть сокрытое от программиста свойство `[[scope]]`, которое ссылается на родительский объект окружения.
При обращении внутренней функции к переменной, сначала смотрится собственное окружение. Если нету - идём к родителю. Если и там нет - к его родителю. И так до конца - объекта `global` (`window` в браузерах).

В картинках:

```
function b(){   | b.LexicalScoping = {x: 42, c: function} | b.[[scope]] = window
  let x = 42;
  function c(){ | c.LexicalScoping = {y: 3}               | c.[[scope]] = b.LexicalScoping
    let y = 3;
    alert(w);
  }
}
```

Когда интерпретатор выполняет `alert(w)`, он ищет переменную `w` и смотрит так: `c.LexicalScoping`, если пусто - `c.[[scope]]`. Если и там пусто - `b.[[scope]]`.
Если и там нет - выбросит ошибку.

Это, конечно, не копирка стандартов, но для новичка объяснение нормально, так что не надо тут флагать, @Grundy!

Comment: Ну Вы задайте вопросы, что именно непонятно. Мы ответим.

Comment: Так я в посте все написал, но после "фабрикой" и "паттернов" из вашего сообщения понял, что после ваших оьяснений яснее не станет

Comment: Если Вы - совсем новичок, то, возможно, стоит начать с более простых вещей. А когда прокачаетесь до знания [фабрики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), то можно и за замыкания браться.

Comment: Тем более что более подробное объяснение есть в дубликате Вашего вопроса.

Comment: ну не так чтобы полный уж нуб, такое чувство что прошел основы, опустив замыкания, колбеки, классы и другие мощные фишки, а сейчас их чет не доганяю... и дубликат я читал, но там тоже чет ясности не внеслось

Comment: @chase, Повторюсь - что именно Вам непонятно? Напишите вопрос и Вам ответят. Сейчас постараюсь на пальцах обрисовать и поправлю ответ.

Comment: @Other, в конце какая-то ерунда написана. Так как скрытого свойства [[scope]] нет. Оно могло быть в ранних версиях, но сейчас именно его нет.

Comment: @Grundy, О великий Знаток священной Спецификации, озари же нас светом Знания! Т. е. серьёзно - напиши как, только не копирую спёку, а передавая её смысл в понятном человекам языке.

Comment: [Where does a JavaScript closure live?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37493113/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy, уиии, переводите тогда!

Comment: А почему здесь https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_function_counter2 counter каждый раз 1? потому что при вызове функции он всегда становится 0, а по щелчку 1?

Comment: @chase, При вызове создаётся область, инициируются переменные, а в начале переменной `counter` прямо задаётся значение 0. Потом плюсуется 1 и отдаётся. 0 + 1 всегда 1.

Comment: ну я ведь также и написал